# Java 17, Spring boot 3.0.3 and hibernate error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.query.BindableType

Tags: hibernate

I am getting this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.query.BindableType`

This is my pom file:

`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.2


fasfasfasfsafsa
fasfasfasfsafsa
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
fasfasfasfsafsa
fasfasfasfsafsa

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    <flyway.version>9.15.2</flyway.version>
    <springdoc-openapi.version>1.6.9</springdoc-openapi.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.15.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>

    <sonar.projectKey>interdiscount_repair-center-service</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.organization>interdiscount</sonar.organization>
    <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    <hibernate-jpamodelgen>6.1.7.Final</hibernate-jpamodelgen>
    <shedlock.version>4.37.0</shedlock.version>
    <easy-rules-core.version>4.1.0</easy-rules-core.version>
    <pdfbox.version>2.0.27</pdfbox.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flyway.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
        <version>${shedlock.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.35.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- shared libs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>easy-rules-core</artifactId>
        <version>${easy-rules-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--                <version>3.8.1</version>-->
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN
                    </compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>
                        -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                    </compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groups>IntegrationTest</groups>
                        <excludedGroups>None</excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

I am trying to migrate from java 11 to java 17 and also from 2.7 Spring boot to 3.0.3 and then I saw that I have an errors with hibernate this is the uptodate Pom file above.

Comment: Hello can you verify if you use this version of hibernate : 5.6.15.Final ? if you want to use the interface org.hibernate.query.BindableType you should switch to Hibernate 6.x